# ORDER BY в PDO

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Имеется такой код:

```
...
function pdq($sql, $params = array()) {
global $pdo; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
return $stmt;
}
$var = 'text2';
$sql = "SELECT pole FROM table ORDER BY :txt2 DESC LIMIT 1";
$res = pdq($sql, [':txt2'=> $var])->fetchColumn();
print_r($res);
```

Необходимо получить максимальное значение из поля text2 и выбрать соответствующий ему "pole", на вышеприведенном коде, почему-то всегда получает значение из поля text1. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Что значит `всегда получает значение из поля text1`? Вместо `pole` возвращается `text1`? Или выбирает pole не у максимального text2, а у максимального text1?

UPD: если выполнить ваш запрос в базе, ответ будет другим?

Comment: И еще... а разве можно поля передавать? Они разве не будут значениями в SQL? Т.е. вы сортируете по константной строке получается, т.е. никак.

Comment: @BOPOH, выбирает pole не у максимального text2, а у максимального text1. Почему по константной?

Comment: Потому что у вас в итоге получается:

    SELECT pole FROM table ORDER BY 'text2' DESC LIMIT 1

Т.е. вы сортируете по строке `text2`, а не по полю. Вам кто сказал, что так можно делать?

Comment: Не подскажите как нужно правильно сделать? Просто совсем не давно на PDO перешел

Comment: @XenK, плейсхолдеры **не принимают значения** для названий таблиц и полей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что мешает прописать поле сразу в sql? Параметры нужны только для параметров, например:

```
SELECT pole FROM table WHERE text2 <= :txt2 ORDER BY text2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

А остальное пишите как есть.

Если что-то надо автоматически подставлять, то можно (как один из вариантов) sprintf использовать, в вашем случае:

```
$sql = sprinf('SELECT pole FROM table ORDER BY %1$s DESC LIMIT 1', 'text2')
```

Тогда запрос будет таким, каким вы хотите. Только аккуратно с кавычками: здесь надо одинарные, т.к. иначе (если использовать %1$s вместо %s) будет искать и вставлять переменную $s.